# Can boost::regex_search be done on a wstring?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

This is what I tried:

```
std::wstring extractText(std::wstring line) {
    std::wstring text;

    boost::regex exp("^.*?PRIVMSG #.*? :(.+)");
    boost::smatch match;

    if (boost::regex_search(line, match, exp)) {
              text = std::wstring(match[1].first, match[1].second);
             }

    return text;
    }
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: error C2784: 'bool boost::regex_search(const std::basic_string<charT,ST,SA> &,const boost::basic_regex<charT,traits> &,boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::basic_regex<charT,traits> &' from 'boost::smatch'

Comment: I believe when you use `std::wstring`, you will have to use the 'w' forms of boost.regex, like `boost::wregex` and `boost::wsmatch`. Also, if you doing Unicode matching, check out this link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use wregex and wsmatch

Answer (score 2):

I believe so, but you'll need to use `boost::wsmatch` instead of `smatch`, and `wregex` as well.

Comment: error C2784: 'bool boost::regex_search(const std::basic_string<charT,ST,SA> &,const boost::basic_regex<charT,traits> &,boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::basic_regex<charT,traits> &' from 'boost::wsmatch'